Is it possible to manually invoke a specific bash-completion function on the command line?
I have several scripts that expect a git branch as argument, rather than specifying the completion mechanism for all of these, is it possible to invoke a specific "completion activity" anywhere in a commandline regardless of what text is currently there?
do_banana_dance <git_branch>
do_banana_dance <ctrl-TAB> -> let user select completion function for git branch-name completion (same as git switch <TAB> would invoke) and then continue with regular completion mechanism to select an item (tabbing, or fzf selector or whatever the user has defined).

check out https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Can't say for sure but :Defining a specific completion behavior requires to run a command, so how will you run that command while typing an other command (do_banana_dance ...)?

You can bind arbitrary shell functions to arbitrary key sequences in Readline. Completion functions are usually written to be executed within a specific context (where certain variables can be expected to have already been defined by the completion framework), though.
